# htaccess LimitInternalRecursion error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file in my website's root directory, and its contents are as below :

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Check if connection is HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

#Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteRule ^user\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteRule ^friends\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)/?$ /friends.php?username=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 400 /errors/1.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/2.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/2.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/4.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/6.php
```

Everything except the rewrite rule for friends.php is working.

If I go to my-domain.com/user/example, I successfully get contents of my-domain.com/profile.php?username=example.

However, when I go to my-domain/friends/example , it gives me an internal server error, and I see this is my apache error log :

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

In debug log, I get the following lines :

```
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [error] [client 122.175.169.57] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3112): [client ###] r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example.php
[Sun May 18 00:42:12 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client ###] redirected from r->uri = /friends/example
```

I cannot see what is wrong with my rules. rewrite rule for /user/example is working like it should. Although, /friends/ has the same rule, it gives me the above error.

Comment: _“What am I missing here?”_ – that the error message already told you what you should do to see what exactly is going on during the rewriting process.

Comment: Btw., `RewriteCond`s only ever work on the one single `RewriteRule` following them immediately – whereas I expect you actually _intended_ to apply them to _both_ of your multiple combinations of two consecutive RewriteRules that only differ in the trailing slash. You will either have to _repeat_ your RewriteConds – or condense those two rules to a single one (which is easily done by making the trailing slash _optional_).

Comment: @CBroe I understand that the error is telling me about large number of redirections. But what I don't know is, what's causing the error?

Comment: Being able to read a message _completely_ ’til the end seems to be a “lost art” nowadays … _*sigh*_ … __“Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.”__

Comment: So your rewriting to add `.php` to PHP files requested without extension seems to catch the request … and rewrites it over and over again. Enable enhanced rewrite logging to see how that happens. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog / http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)

Comment: I tried setting RewriteLogLevel to 9
and RewriteLog to "/var/www/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
but when I check the file (after the error ofcourse), the file is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I moved :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteRule ^user\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteRule ^friends\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)/?$ /friends.php?username=$1 [L]
```

above :

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

which seemed to add .php in a loop. Now all rules are working perfectly.